# offsetHeight / clientHeight / scrollHeight never change

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a scrolling directive with Angular and see a strange behavior of element heights. They do not change on resize. I went down to the simplest plain JS, but the bug is still here. This fiddle illustrates it http://jsfiddle.net/Y8B86/1/. Try to resize the window and click contents several times and see the console.

```
function rebuild() {
    var transcluded = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
    scope.scrollHeight = transcluded.scrollHeight;
    scope.offsetHeight = transcluded.offsetHeight;
    scope.clientHeight = transcluded.clientHeight;
}
```

This function is responsible for reading values. The only difference in Angular is that instead of `document.getElementsByTagName` i do `element.children()[n]` to get inner element.
Also, the element does not respond to scrolling when window is small enough. ScrollTop does not change.

The question is why `height` is not updated **after** window reports resize?

Comment: when do you want the response?  just when window is resized?

Comment: The `div` is not changed in any way on resize, hence the values are kept.

Comment: @z.a. To say the truth, it doesn't matters. I just cannot get why these values do not change. But the main purpose is to handle viewport change and rebuild scrollbar accordingly.

Comment: @Teemu Ok, but if you replace `div` with `body` or `html` in `getElementsByTagName` nothing happens also

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the problem is that you're expecting scrollHeight, offsetHeight, and clientHeight to change based on the windows size which in fact this is not the case.

The scrollHeight is "a measurement of the height of an element's content including content not visible on the screen due to overflow" ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollHeight)).

The offsetHeight is "the height of the element including vertical padding and borders, in pixels, as an integer" ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetHeight)).

The clientHeight is "the inner height of an element in pixels, including padding but not the horizontal scrollbar height, border, or margin"([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.clientHeight)).

All three of these are relative to the element for which they are called on. Since it doesn't seem like you have set a relative height for the elements, you will not see any change to their scrollHeight, offsetHeight, or clientHeight. In other words, the elements currently have fixed heights based on the content within them.

You can see this when you make the screen so small that the 'click me' goes across two lines, then your values change.

Comment: Sorry, no. I am listening for window size change (`resize` event) to update scrollbar size.

Comment: @EugeneKostrikov I updated the answer, I hope that makes things clearer.

Comment: Thanks! It seems I have gathered wits finally. Somehow I was absolutely sure that `clientHeight` represents height of a visible part and `offsetHeight` shows how "far" the element has been scrolled. Amazing! I have no idea how I came to that :)

Answer (score 0):

you can plug this into your link function in your directive,

```
angular.element($window).bind('resize', function () {
   rebuild();
});
```

make sure to inject `$window` into the directive function,
and just call rebuild or another function inside.  of course, you should also change the transcluded to the appropriate angularJS form.

Comment: This is actually what I do to catch `resize` event with Angular :) But the question is why `height`s are not updated.

Comment: you have to transform the transcluded variable.  you cant just call document inside a directive function.  for one thing it's global, for second, you shouldn't.  test if your resizing binding works first, then try to change the transcluded to something related to your directive.